# Is there a way to get the position of the "ghost image" when dragging an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I was wondering if there is a way to get the position of the dragged ghost image of an element.

The setup is as follows:

```
<div id="test" v-on:dragstart="dragStart" v-on:drag="dragging" draggable="true" v-on:drop="drop" v-on:dragover="allowDrop"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the position of the ghost image will be the same as the position of the pointer / mouse pointer. Since you are using jQuery, these coordinates (position) can be acquired this way:

```
$("body").mousemove(function(e) {
    console.log('position of ghost image: ' + e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY;
})
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Thanks!